# question about mlp() in tidymodels

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I was reading `tidymodels` and got confused about `mlp()` function's description from help section. it says from R help file,

> mlp() defines a multilayer perceptron model (a.k.a. a single layer, feed-forward neural network). This function can fit classification and regression models.

I am confused how **a multilayer perception model** becomes **a single layer, feed-forward neural network**?

Could someone enlighten me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a model with a single *hidden* layer, plus the input and output layers, with all nodes connected from one layer to the next. That's the simplest case of multilayer perceptron (see eg [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron)).

For a long time there was a bit of tendency in statistics to consider *only* the single-hidden-layer case of neural networks, until deep convolutional networks such as AlexNet showed that more layers could really matter in practice. For example, even the second edition of *Elements of Statistical Learning* (from 2008), by definitely computation-friendly authors, restricts itself to a single hidden layer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the explanation is confusing. The a.k.a. section refers to "perceptron model", not "multilayer perceptron model".

You can sense this from the tinymodel definition of [MLP](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/mlp.html):

```
mlp(
  mode = "unknown",
  engine = "nnet",
  hidden_units = NULL,
  penalty = NULL,
  dropout = NULL,
  epochs = NULL,
  activation = NULL,
  learn_rate = NULL
)
```

It's a complete model, not single layer because we do not talk about number of epochs, penalty (and usually learning rate) for a single layer of the neural network.

Comment: Thank you, guys! Your explanations clarify my confusion. It's indeed a single hidden layer neural network